# How to fix a bad resizing in qt label?

Tags: c++, qt, resize, qtwidgets

I am currently learning to use Qt. So I am trying to create an application that uses QtWidgets. However, when I ran my program and resize manually the window obtained, the texts displayed are trimmed (see image)

[image].

The code I am using is shown below:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "FenPrincipale.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    FenPrincipale fenetre;
    fenetre.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

and the `FenPrincipale` contains:

```
FenPrincipale::FenPrincipale()
{
    QWidget mainFen;
    QGroupBox *groupbox1 = new QGroupBox("Class definition", &mainFen);
    QLineEdit *className = new QLineEdit;
    QLineEdit *mother_className = new QLineEdit;

    QFormLayout *class_def = new QFormLayout;
    class_def->addRow("Class name", className);
    class_def->addRow("Mother Class", mother_className);

    groupbox1->setLayout(class_def);

    QGroupBox *groupbox2 = new QGroupBox("Options", &mainFen);
    QCheckBox *header_protect = new QCheckBox("Protect header against mutiple inclusions");
    QCheckBox *constr_gen= new QCheckBox("Generate default constructor");
    QCheckBox *destruct_gen= new QCheckBox("Generate a destructor");

    QVBoxLayout *options_layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    options_layout->addWidget(header_protect);
    options_layout->addWidget(constr_gen);
    options_layout->addWidget(destruct_gen);

    groupbox2->setLayout(options_layout);

    QVBoxLayout *main_layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    main_layout->addWidget(groupbox1);
    main_layout->addWidget(groupbox2);

    this->setLayout(main_layout);
    this->setWindowTitle("Zero Class Generator");
    this->resize(400,450);
}
```

I don't have any idea how to fix this problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Apart from anything else you're using a locally scoped `QWidget` `mainFen` as the parent of various other widgets.  That will cause those child widgets to be deleted when `mainFen` goes out of scope at the end of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
QWidget::setMinimumSize
```

should make the job

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMinimumSize-1